# Property Declaration within a Class Conversion from Vb.net to C#

Tags: c#, class, properties, declaration

I have to following in vb.net and am having a rough time converting to c#.    The fieldlist is a class that has several properties however only 2 are relevant for the below procedure. The code to call the procedure looks like myClass.Fields("Test") = 123456.   The converters all drop the fieldname from the property.  If I add it back then I get The name 'value' does not exist in the current context.

VB.net - works fine in VB

```
 Public WriteOnly Property Fields(ByVal fieldName As String) As Object
    Set(ByVal value As Object)
        If mvarFieldData Is Nothing Then mvarFieldData = New FieldList
        If mvarFieldData(fieldName) Is Nothing Then
            mvarFieldData.Add(fieldName, value)
        Else
            mvarFieldData(fieldName).FieldValue = value
        End If
    End Set
End Property
```

c#  - I'm doing something wrong here.

```
public object Fields(string fieldName)
{
   set {
       if (mvarFieldData == null) 
        {mvarFieldData = new FieldList();}
        if (mvarFieldData[fieldName] == null) 
        {
            mvarFieldData.Add(fieldName, value);
        } else {
            mvarFieldData[fieldName].FieldValue = value;
        }
    }
}
```

c# Converters(telerik) provide the below

```
public object Fields {
set {
    if (mvarFieldData == null)
        mvarFieldData = new FieldList();
    if (mvarFieldData(fieldName) == null) {
        mvarFieldData.Add(fieldName, value);
    } else {
        mvarFieldData(fieldName).FieldValue = value;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Why are you adding fieldName back?

Comment: Unlike VB.NET, C# doesn't support named indexers. It only suppoers default indexers.

Answer (score 1):

What is the scope of mVarFieldData, and what is it's exact type? It seems like it is a Collection of some sort.
The c# code above is not compilable as you are trying to mix a method syntax with a property syntax.
property:

```
public object Fields{ get; set{mvarFieldData = value;} }
```

Method:

```
public object Fields(string fieldname, object val){ mvarFieldData[fieldname] = val;}
```

By the looks of the decision making going on in the VB.Net property, I would think a public method may suit the situation better. I normally just use property's when a very minimum amount of validation is needed when setting a encapsulated type member.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You actually have a couple problems here.

**Problem 1: Properties don't take arguments.**

C# properties can't be passed an argument/parameter the way you're passing fieldname. There are a couple different ways you could solve this:

1. You can make an index property (used with `myObject[fieldName] = blah` rather than `myObject.Fields[fieldName] = blah`). Use the syntax `public object this[string fieldName]` to declare the property.
2. Since your property doesn't have a getter, you can just turn it into a single method with signature `public void SetField(string fieldName, object value)`, called like so: `myObject.SetField(fieldName, value)`.
3. You can expose `mvarFieldData` through a getter property: `public Dictionary<?, ?> Fields { get { return mvarFieldData; } }` which will let users access the dictionary (I assume that's what it is, based on usage) directly.

**Problem 2: The key may not exist.**

I'm not sure about dictionaries (or whatever similar structure `mvarFieldData` is) in VB.NET, but in C# there's a difference between a key whose value is null and a key that's not present in the structure.

```
var dict = new Dictionary<int, string>();
dict.Add(1, null);
if (dict[1] == null)
    Console.WriteLine("This line will be displayed.");
if (dict[2] == null)
    Console.WriteLine("The line above this one will throw an exception.");
```

In addition to your present code, you need a check for `mvarFieldData.ContainsKey(fieldName)` before you start checking the value associated with `fieldName`.